# Why the new thread can't handle the arguments that i passed to it?

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, struct

I'm creating a thread to which I pass a struct. Anyway, in the new thread, each single value of the struct is 0. Why? Thank you so much for your help.
This is the struct:

```
struct distance{
    int lat;
    int lon;
    int id;
    int sign;
};
```

This is the code snippet where I create the new thread (the values assigned to the struct elements are obviously not zero).

```
                pthread_attr_t distance_attr;
                int distance_status;

                setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IOLBF, 0);

                distance_status = pthread_attr_init(&distance_attr);
                if (distance_status)
                {
                    (void)(fprintf(stderr, "Unable to initialize PThread attributes %d\n", distance_status));
                }

                distance_status = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&distance_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
                if (distance_status)
                {
                    (void)(fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set thread detached state in PThread attributes %d\n",
                                   distance_status));
                }

                pthread_t distance_thread1;
                struct distance s;
                int lat = alfa;
                int lon = beta;
                int id =  gamma;
                s.lat = lat;
                s.lon = lon;
                s.id = id;
                s.sign = 1;
                
                distance_status = pthread_create(&distance_thread1, &distance_attr, &thread_function, &s);

                distance_status = pthread_attr_destroy(&distance_attr);
                if (distance_status)
                {
                    (void)(fprintf(stderr, "Unable to destroy PThread attributes %d\n", distance_status));
                }
```

And here is the thread:

```
static void *thread_function(void *Ptr)
{

    struct distance *my_struct = (struct distance *)Ptr;

    int lat = my_struct->lat;
    int lon = my_struct->lon;
    int id = my_struct->id;
    int sign = my_struct->sign;

    printf("thread: %d %d %d %d\n", my_struct->lat, lat, lon, sign);

    return (void *)0;
}
```

Comment: printf("thread: %d %d %d %d\n", my_struct->lat, lat, lon, sign) -> ALL THIS VALUES ARE ZERO.. thank you for your support!

Comment: The function that starts the thread could be returning before the thread finishes, causing the lifetime of `s` to end before the thread can read the fields.  Try allocating the struct dynamically in the calling function and freeing it in the thread.

Comment: Thank for your help, ma this doesn't solve my problem... I really don't know why this happens..

Comment: Then your question needs more detail.  Please update it to include a [mcve].

Comment: Agree with dbush, this needs code that people can actually compile, run, and test.  Snippets won't suffice.